# How to make a single event emit multiple items in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I'm binding together SVG graphics and mouse/touch events, using RxJS.

One of the challenges is that on iOS, a single `touchstart` event can carry multiple touch data. When it's just one, I can trivially use `select` and convert each `TouchEvent` to an observable of coordinates (i.e. each touch start initiates a new drag). But how can I add 2 or 3 entries to the observable, from just the single event?

Not sure if `flatMap` is the thing. Maybe `selectMany` is? I've read the manuals but they are ... a bit entangled and full of streamy language.

The lines in question are <s>[these](https://github.com/akauppi/svg.rx.js/blob/ios/src/svg.rx.js#L201-L231)</s>. If you are interested in making interactive SVG graphics in a browser easier to program for, welcome to help with the project!

Comment: your link is broken ("these")

Comment: Thanks for informing. Unfortunately GitHub links are pretty momentary. What worked is mentioned in my answer below - hope that helps.

Comment: Cool np good question

Answer (score 6):

`selectMany` is the same as `flatMap`.
RxJS provides some examples, also for Drag'n'Drop, you can find it [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/dragndrop/dragndrop.js).

If this doesn't fit your needs, you can use a [Rx.Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md) to send notifications around, e.g.

```
var oneSubject = new Rx.Subject();
var otherSubject = new Rx.Subject();
someObservable.subscribe(function(x) {
    oneSubject.onNext('hello');
    otherSubject.onNext(42);
});

// subscribe to oneSubject or otehrSubject
```

**EDIT**
If you mean with "one event to multiple items" that you get an x and want to send n times x, then you can also use [repeat](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/repeat.md), e.g. `n = 10`

```
someObservable.flatMap(function(x) { return Rx.Observable.repeat(x, 10); });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Chasmo The samples really helped - RxJS documentation itself is more of a legal text. :) Will likely give my own answer below, to point what worked. Your input still appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `.selectMany` is really rather trivial to use, it seems.

Whereas for `select` one would convert an input value to an output (emitted) value, for `.selectMany` one returns an array or observable (both work) of the 0..n values one wishes to emit. That's it. :)

My code ended up being like this:

```
return range( 0, ev.changedTouches.length ).map( function (i) {
  return touchDragObs( ev, i );
} );
```

The `range` is a helper function to create an 0..n-1 seed array:

```
// JavaScript does not have an Array for range constructor.
//
function range( start, count ) {    // (Int,Int) -> Array of Int
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
    arr[i]= start+i;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Another option would be this (both work):

```
return Rx.Observable         
  .range(0,ev.changedTouches.length)   // (start, count)
  .select( function (i) {
    return touchDragObs( ev, i );         
});
```

If anyone knows the performance indications of the above options, I'd like to know.